# Open a modal with passed data in MVC

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

I have a list of of objects and when i click on any of them i want a modal to open with the data of the clicked object. I thought it is a simple task but i just can't make it work. I want to pass the clicked object or its index to a js function which opens the modal

```
<button data-toggle="modal" OnClick="objectClick(i)" data-target="#modalDiv">Delete</button>


<div id="modalDiv" class="modal></div>

function objectClick(car) {
        $("#modalDiv").load('@{
                Html.RenderPartial("deleteCarPartialView", car);
            }');
    }
```

but its uses `@Html.RenderPartial` in which i can't use the js parameters. I tried set it in the onClick like this `<button onClick="@{selectedIndex = i;} objectClick()"></button>` but for some reason the C# code runs when the page load and not when i click the object, so the value of selectedIndex will be the last index in the list. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to pass data to action,and get partial view html code from action,here is a demo:

Car:

```
public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }

    }
```

Action:

```
public class CController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Car> l = new List<Car> { new Car { Id = 1, Name = "car1", Price = 10000 }, new Car { Id = 2, Name = "car2", Price = 20000 }, new Car { Id = 3, Name = "car3", Price = 30000 } };
            return View(l);
        }
        public IActionResult GetPartial(Car car)
        {
            return PartialView("deleteCarPartialView", car);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@model IEnumerable<Car>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @{ var i = 0;} 
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="@i">
                <td>@item.Id</td>
                <td>@item.Name</td>
                <td>@item.Price</td>
                <td><button data-toggle="modal" OnClick="objectClick(@i)" data-target="#modalDiv">Delete</button></td>

            </tr>
            i++;
        }
        
    </tbody>
</table> 
<div class="modal fade" id="modalDiv" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Car Detail</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modalContent">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
<script>
        function objectClick(index) {
            var car = {};
            car.Id = parseInt($("#" + index).find("td")[0].innerText);
            car.Name = $("#" + index).find("td")[1].innerText;
            car.Price = parseInt($("#" + index).find("td")[2].innerText);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "GetPartial",
                data: car,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#modalContent").html(data);
                }
            });

    }
    </script>
```

deleteCarPartialView.cshtml:

```
@model Car
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Id)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
    </dd>
</dl>
```

result:
[image]